# How to convert Object[] to JSONArray in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, json

In my app, I got an Object[] from socketio. and i want to use JSON to parse that. but how should i do that?

in details:

```
           socketio.connect("XXXXXXXXX",new IOCallback() {

            @Override
            public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack,
                    Object... args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Server triggered event:  " + event + " ack: " + ack + " args: " + args);
                switch(event){
                case "msg":
                    parseMSG(args); 
                }
            }
```

so from here, the value of "args" is something like:

```
[{"a":"aaaa","b":"bbbbbb"}]
```

it's a json array, so in the  "parseMSG[args]"  i wanna parse this object and here's my code:

```
public void parseMSG(Object[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {

        JSONArray inLine = new JSONArray(args);
        JSONObject jb = inLine.getJSONObject(0);
        ......}
    }
```

but the problem here is, I'm actually converted args from

```
Object [] to JSONArray
```

so Android warned me this is only works in API 19. My question is are there anyway i can use json to parse this object that is supported from API 17~ 19?

Comment: you could use the string that represent the JSONArray as parameter,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every class in JAVA directly or indirectly inherits from **Object** class. So it can be cast to any class. A small sample. You need to catch exception like JsonException yourself:

```
String str = (String) args[0]; // your Object is variable argument so access it via index like array
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(str);
```

Comment: *your Object is variable argements thats why the index* what does it mean?

Comment: @blackbelt typo i meant to say **Object... args** is a var-arg so to it will require an index like args[0]; thanks for clarification

Comment: @IllegalArgument thanks a lot.I converted the object[] to string and then use them in JSONArray, it works very well!!! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There is a great library that I often use to convert my Data Model classes to JSON.. you can just pass it a class and it will generate Json including arrays:

**GSON**

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list

Comment: thanks a lot. I converted the array to the string first and then use it in the JSONArray, it's easier for me. Thanks for you lib!

Comment: no problem, your case is simple enough you don't need it.  But it is quite useful when building an app that requires extensive data models that are used with API's  good luck